# Casting entites from different modules with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, type-conversion, mapping

I have two modules, module A and module B, each module have its own data classes FOO and Pl

```
data class Foo ( var title : String, list : List<Pl>)

data class Pl ( var title : String, list : List<String>)
```

I want to cast/convert  an object, from module A, to be used in another module B.

I already converted that by mapping each attribute but I am just looking for a better solution(if exist with kotlin), because the first one makes boilerplate code.

Comment: What is the dependency hierarchy between the two modules? Can you not simply define the classes once in the the top-level module?

Comment: Module A implements module B.
Module B will be published as dependency, that why I duplicated the data class.
Module A retrieve the data from a data source and send it to module B